# Buscar arquivo tendo somente parte do nome dele em C#

Tags: c#, arquivo, dialog

Estou precisando localizar um arquivo automaticamente sem precisar abrir um caixa de seleção para o usuário selecionar o arquivo.
Onde eu já tenho o diretório da pasta onde esse arquivo irá ficar e sei também o parte do nome final desse arquivo, sendo que essa parte final nunca irá se repetir. Cheguei a fazer esse código aqui abaixo mas não obtive sucesso, pois eu consigo obter todos os arquivo deste diretório mas não estou conseguindo identificar o arquivo que termine com o nome informado:

```
private string localizarArquivo()
    {
        DirectoryInfo diretorio = new DirectoryInfo(NFe.DiretorioLog); // C:\Users\WIN\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Demo NFe - VS2012 - C#\bin\Debug\Log\
        string chave = edtIdNFe.Text.Trim();
        string ParteFinal = chave + "-env-sinc-ret.xml"; // 26151003703802000156550100000004521376169520-env-sinc-ret.xml

        string ArquivoLog = String.Empty; // Deverá ser: diretorio + ??????? +  ParteFinal

        foreach (FileInfo f in diretorio.GetFiles())
        {
            if (f.Extension.ToLower() == ParteFinal)
                ArquivoLog = f.ToString();
        }

        if (File.Exists(ArquivoLog))
            return ArquivoLog;

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer usando Linq

```
var arquivos = diretorio.GetFiles().Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith(ParteFinal));
```

Se você tem certeza de que só existe um arquivo, pode usar o `Single()`

```
var arquivo = diretorio.GetFiles().Single(x => x.Name.EndsWith(ParteFinal));
```

Answer (score 4):

Ao invés de

```
foreach (FileInfo f in diretorio.GetFiles())
```

utilize

```
foreach (FileInfo f in diretorio .GetFiles("*" + ParteFinal))
```

Assim a fonte de seu forEach já virá filtrada, contento apenas os arquivos cujos nomes correspondam à mascara.

Answer (score 2):

A titulo de curiosidade, também pode utilizar [`EnumerateFiles(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Ao contrario de `GetFiles(...)` que faz a busca na totalidade e so depois retorna um `string[]`, `EnumerateFiles(...)` retorna um `IEnumerable` que pode ser iterado de forma preguiçosa.

Assim, a utilização seria:

```
foreach(var f in directorio.EnumerateFiles(string.Format("*{0}*", ParteFinal))
{}
```

Nota, se quiser procurar nos subdirectorios, utilize o *overload* [`EnumerateFiles(string, SearchOption)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413343%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
foreach(var f in directorio.EnumerateFiles(string.Format("*{0}*", ParteFinal), SearchOptions.AllDirectories)
{}
```